# How to use checkboxes using simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

My code is as below :

```
    <% for market_language in @pyr_market_languages %>
        <%= f.input :"pyr_crm_call_script[market_language_ids][]", :as => :check_box, input_html:{value: market_language.id}, @callscript.market_languages.include?(market_language) %>
        <%= market_language.name %><br/>
    <% end %>
```

I just want to use simple form tag for checkbox like f.input,because i couldn't see the errors for checkbox field even if it is mandatory.

Can any one of you provide the way of using checkbox in a simple form in rails.

Comment: Try like his `f.input :field_name, as: :boolean`

Comment: Why mix Hash syntaxes? Try `:as => :check_box, :input_html =>`